# Setting up diskless PCs(client) to use servers hardisk

Tags: networking, nas

I am planning to start an internet cafe business (10 PCs)

1. What software do i used so that i will only have one hardisk(server) used by the client PCs?
2. Since this will used a lot of networking, do i need to have a fast router?

Comment: what OS are the clients? You will likely want/need to use gigabit ethernet, and proper routers.

Comment: windows xp. What do you mean by proper routers?

Comment: something more powerful than your average consumer level routers.

Comment: ok thanks. how about the server, average specs will do since the processing is more on the router and the server is sending and receiving packets?

Comment: you'll need a load of disk throughput. http://www.etherboot.org/wiki/sanboot/winxp is worth reading, as is http://kentonsprojects.blogspot.sg/2011/12/lan-party-house-technical-design-and.html